# How to Get Value over Array (i,j) in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm Begginer using Google script

**i have date like this :**

| data | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 3 |

using my code bellow

```
function learn(){


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cells = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var columnCount = cells.getNumColumns();
  var rowCount = cells.getNumRows();
//cells.getCell(rowCount, columnCount).getValues(writeHello);
var adressrow;
var addresses = sheet.getRange(cells.getRow(), cells.getColumn(), rowCount, columnCount ).getValues();
var i;
Logger.log(addresses);
for (addressRow = 1; addressRow <= rowCount; ++addressRow) {
  var inputt= cells.getCell(addressRow, 1).getValue();
       for ( var i =1;i <= 3;++i) { 

              var tesrange = sheet.getRange(cells.getRow(),2,rowCount,2).setValue(inputt);

               // angka 3 akan di ganti sesuai jumlah parsing JSON

//Logger.log(tesrange);
}
}
/*Logger.log(sheet);
Logger.log(cells);
Logger.log(columnCount);
Logger.log(rowCount);
Logger.log(addresses);
Logger.log(adressrow);*/

}
```

but the result like this

[cek here for video result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U02mc.gif)

end of data result just like this

| data | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

Assuming you would like to get column A as your input and then produce the desired result in column B.

The basic idea is to use [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) which repeats a specific number `n` number of times. This will make your code cleaner and faster.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const n = 3; // number of times you want to repeat
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const input = sh.getRange("A2:A4").getValues().flat();
  var result = [];
  input.forEach(v=>{
     result.push(Array(n).fill(v));          
  });
  result = result.flat().map(v=>[v]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,result.length,1).setValues(result);
}
```

**Sheet that works with the script:**

[image]